# Not able to adress field in nested query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have such a query:

```
select d.r_object_id,

    (select max(max_date) from (

        SELECT max(sys_s.r_modify_date) AS max_date
        FROM kc_mission_s mis_s, dm_sysobject_s sys_s
        WHERE mis_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id AND mis_s.ka_document = d.r_object_id

        union all

        SELECT sys_s.r_modify_date AS max_date
        FROM dm_document_s doc_s left join dm_sysobject_s sys_s on doc_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id
        WHERE doc_s.r_object_id = d.r_object_id

    )) as maxx

from kc_document_s d
```

The field `d.r_object_id` is not visible from the last nested query.
It will be visible if in-between query will be removed like this:

```
select d.r_object_id,

    (
        SELECT max(sys_s.r_modify_date) AS max_date
        FROM kc_mission_s mis_s, dm_sysobject_s sys_s
        WHERE mis_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id AND mis_s.ka_document = d.r_object_id

        union all

        SELECT sys_s.r_modify_date AS max_date
        FROM dm_document_s doc_s left join dm_sysobject_s sys_s on doc_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id
        WHERE doc_s.r_object_id = d.r_object_id

    ) as maxx

from kc_document_s d
```

But in this case I'm not allowed to select multiple rows.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you continue the join from the middle level query into the lowest level query, and also include the join column at each level, then it should work

```
select d.r_object_id,
    (select max(max_date) from (
        SELECT max(sys_s.r_modify_date) AS max_date,
        d.r_object_id
        FROM kc_mission_s mis_s, dm_sysobject_s sys_s
        WHERE mis_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id AND mis_s.ka_document = d.r_object_id

        union all

        SELECT sys_s.r_modify_date AS max_date,
        d.r_object_id
        FROM dm_document_s doc_s left join dm_sysobject_s sys_s on doc_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id
        WHERE doc_s.r_object_id = d.r_object_id
    ) sub_query
      where sub_query.r_object_id = d.r_object_id
    ) as maxx
from kc_document_s d
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select d.r_object_id,
       greatest((select max(sys_s.r_modify_date) as max_date
          from kc_mission_s mis_s, dm_sysobject_s sys_s
         where mis_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id
           and mis_s.ka_document = d.r_object_id), 
        (select sys_s.r_modify_date as max_date
          from dm_document_s doc_s
          left join dm_sysobject_s sys_s
            on doc_s.r_object_id = sys_s.r_object_id
         where doc_s.r_object_id = d.r_object_id)
        ) as maxx
  from kc_document_s d
```